# SharePoint Designer Workflow Condition Evaluation

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am trying to find information on how SPD workflow conditionals are evaluated.

What I'd like to do is if (a or b) and (c or d) then, and my brief tests make it appear like it will work that way if I create it:

If a = green1
or b = green2
and c = green1
or d = green2
set status to green

Is there any documentation on the behavior? I have to implement this in a rather tedious determination process and would like to only have to do it once, and would prefer to avoid a lot of nested conditionals.

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: Upon further testing, my example does not work. Seems that it just evaluates them in order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 2 little evaluations:
Step 1
If (a or b) add 1 to workflow variable.
If (c or d) add 1 to workflow variable.
Step 2
if workflow variable = 2
update status = green

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, what I did was changed my approach to the workflow. I made this the else condition and built the rest of the conditional around that. I couldn't just use nested conditionals because it became nested too deep and threw and error.